# node.js download file with http.request to another api

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

i'm trying to write file to the file system with data sent as a response of http.request. When i call the function file is created on desktop but it contains only text: [Object object]. Question is how do i get the actual file data from http.request response and how do i write it to a file. When i directly call the api from rest client like postman, the file downloads perfectly, but when node sends the call it doensn't work.
Here is my code:

```
exports.fileDownload = function(req, res){
//Options are defined here

var request = http.request(options, function (res, err) {
    if(err){
        //Error handling
    }
});

request.on('error', function (e) {
    //Error handling
});    

request.on('response', function(data){       
    fs.writeFile("C:/Users/Test/Desktop/file.txt", data, 'binary', function(err){
        if(err){
            //Error handling
        }
        else{
            console.log("Done");
        }
    })

})
request.end()
}
```

What is wrong here, so when this function is invoked, it creates file named file.txt with [Object object] text in it, and not the actual text of the file. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http.request` returns a response object in the callback, containing the headers etc. You have to bind an event handler to that response object and wait for the actual data, something like this :

```
exports.fileDownload = function (req, res) {
    //Options are defined here

    var request = http.request(options, function (resp, err) {
        if (err) {
            //Error handling
        } else {
            resp.on('data', function (chunk) {
                fs.writeFile("C:/Users/Test/Desktop/file.txt", chunk, function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        //Error handling
                    } else {
                        console.log('Done');
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
    request.end();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however using the code above doesn't end the request properly, do i need to write something to request body with request.write() before ending it or do i have to call request.end() from somewhere else?

Comment: @Case09 - Actually, I was thinking async, and that you had to wait for the request to end it, but in the DOCS, they end it on the next line, so try that. Edited the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps add:

resp.on('end', function () {

// do something

});

You get/send all the data only after the 'end' event fires.